# Python - Gathering statistics from different scripts

Tags: python

I've written a program in Python that takes data (any kind), organizes it, and sends it to a remote service for visualization. The API just needs a configuration file that specifies what types of data it should expect, and then it's ready to go.

I then have lots of different programs that all report some form of statistics in their execution. What i want to do is to be able to connect them to my API **without having to modify the programs themselves** and this is proving tricky.

It's possible to just instantiate an object of the API in each class and then call on the methods provided, however this is too much of a hassle - you should be able to use it without having the API-classes in your own repository.

One solution we came up with was to simply print all of the output into a file, and have the API listen to this file - once it detected something new, it would read it and send it off. However, this is too slow for our needs as some of the program produce vast amounts of data very quickly.

Is there any other solution to my problem?

Thanks!